# Making an whole app invisible even from application manager also in android

Tags: java, android, c++, security, android-camera

I am making one security related application in android so i am looking for three solution
1. my application should be invisible (like service or keylogger) but whole application should not be visible in setting-> application manger 
2. All the activity should be visible on some secure key(predefine shortcut) pressed in mobile
3. i want access camera(front camera) without creating sound and image should be saved without preview.

Comment: this sounds like a malware application... I don't think this is possible

Comment: @gabi this is a mobile tracker where unknown user can not delete the application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do this on Android devices.